# Google vision fails to identify numbers in a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am aiming to extract a table of text & numbers from a document using Google's Vision API. The results are far from satisfactory - Vision seems to completely miss the contents of 2 columns in my table.

Recognition rate improves when I manually erase the column border but I cannot pre-process each file which I intend to process.
Cropping the column text, MOVing the column text to a new location dont seem to make a difference.
Increasing the brightness/contrast of the document seems to help a little bit but not enough to be satisfactory.
I'm using the "Try-It" web interface at cloud.google.com/vision/docs/drag-and-drop to test all my experiments... It mimics the results of running my code on the document.
I'm uploading JPG images, created from scanned PDF originals (converted in photoshop).

I dont have any code since the problem shows up just using the web-tool.

many of the numbers are single digits but many are not.
The numbers missed are 1,3,4,8,500,1,16,100,10
Other columns (which ARE read ok) contain decimal numbers

Perhaps there are some tricks/tips that I've not found that I can use?

Comment: Can you provide the image that the service fails to detect those two columns in it?